# Error in nearest neighbor search in PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to write a PostGIS nearest neighbor query where a set of coordinates are selected and the distance from closest polygon of flooding is determined. I then want to categorize the distance as either 'OUTSIDE, 'CLOSE' OR 'INSIDE':

```
WITH 
  point_loc (geom) AS ( 
    SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(531673.0, 180848.2),27700) ),
  distances (gid, distance) AS (
    SELECT  
      fl.gid,
      ST_Distance(fl.geom, p.geom) AS distance
    FROM
      point_loc p, flooding fl
    WHERE ST_DWithin(p.geom, fl.geom, 400)
  SELECT 
    gid,
    CASE WHEN distance > 300 THEN 'OUTSIDE'
         WHEN distance > 50 AND <= 300 THEN 'CLOSE'
         ELSE 'INSIDE'
    END as flood_result
  FROM distances;
```

I keep getting a syntax error on the final SELECT call. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis on your second CTE.

This line:
`WHERE ST_DWithin(p.geom, fl.geom, 400)`

Should be:
`WHERE ST_DWithin(p.geom, fl.geom, 400) )`